# How to switch whether to add data to JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there any smart way to switch whether to append items to JSON depending on some condition?
I know how to add/delete an item to JSON but I want to know the idea for reducing messy codes.

Let me explain my need with the example shown below.
I want to set the value `"test2"` to `item2` when `condition` is **true**.
But if `condition` is **false**, `item2` will not be added.

```
const condition = false;

const json = {
    item1: "test1",
    item2: (condition ? "test2" : unset) // This code is wrong.
};

console.log(json);
// Desired result -> { item1: "test1" }
```

Of course, I understand that it can be realized by the code shown below.

```
const condition = false;

const json = {
    item1: "test1"
};

if (condition) {
    json.item2 = "item2";
}
```

However, if there are a lot of items to add, the code becomes less readable.

```
const condition2 = false;
const condition3 = false;
const condition4 = false;

const json = {
    item1: "test1"
};

if (condition2) {
    json.item2 = "item2";
}
if (condition3) {
    json.item3 = "item3";
}
if (condition4) {
    json.item4 = "item4";
}
```

So far, an idea that somewhat meets my needs is shown below.

```
const condition2 = false;
const condition3 = false;
const condition4 = false;

const json = {
    item1: "test1",
    ...(condition2 ? { test2: "test2" } : null),
    ...(condition3 ? { test3: "test3" } : null),
    ...(condition4 ? { test4: "test4" } : null)
};
```

If anyone knows a smarter way than this, it would be appreciated if you could show me.

Comment: Pedantic note: none of this is json.  You're constructing javascript objects.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, there are a number of reasonable ways to do this. One I might suggest is an array of objects that capture the condition, key, and value. Iterate through it and add the appropriate ones to the object.

```js
const toAdd = [
  { condition: false, key: "someKey", value: "someValue" },
  { condition: false, key: "someKey1", value: "someValue1" },
  { condition: false, key: "someKey2", value: "someValue2" },
]

const json = {
    item1: "test1"
};

for (const item of toAdd) {
  if (item.condition) {
    json[item.key] = item.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Nick. Thanks for the suggestion. Your idea is reasonable and I want to think about using this technique in the other projects.

Now I'm looking for simpler code that is easier to read and understand.
For example, the way to assign values ​​directly in the json without using a for statement is welcome.